# how to get the whole row value on click of checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following table:

```
 Select   Service Bundle        WorkFlow
          SB1                   Wf1
          SB2                   SB2
```

On select of checkbox, i have to get row value and need to keep on the json array as below:

```
[{
    servicebundle: "SB1",
    Workflow: "wf1"
}, {
    servicebundle: "SB2",
    Workflow: "wf"
}]
```

Is it possible to do?
Please suggest.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: var values=new Array();
 $.each($("input[name='pakCheckBox']:checked").parents("td").siblings(), function() {
        values.push($(this).text());
        alert("val---"+values);

 }); It gives values but i m not able to keep in key and value pair

Comment: var values=new Array(); $.each($("input[name='pakCheckBox']:checked").parents("td").siblings(), function() { values.push($(this).text()); alert("val---"+values); }); It gives values but i m not able to keep in key and value pair

Comment: you need to edit your question and add this. also please provide some HTML as well

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

try making your table like the following
assign classes to targeted `td` as I have named these classes `sb` and `wf`

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>select</th>
        <th>Service Bundle </th>
        <th>WorkFlow </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>select</td>
        <td class='sb'>sb1</td>
        <td class='wf'>wf1</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>select</td>
        <td class='sb'>sb2</td>
        <td class='wf'>wf2</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="result"> Result will be shown here </div>

<!--after loading jquery.js-->

$(function(){

    var obj  = [];
    $("table tbody tr").each(function(){
        var arr = {};
        arr['sb'] = $(this).find("td.sb").html();
        arr['wf'] = $(this).find("td.wf").html();
        obj.push(arr);
    });
   $("#result").html("<pre>"+JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2));

});
```

live demo  http://jsfiddle.net/3rdwcn97/

Comment: Thank you for the response. When i tried it onclick of check box, i m not getting the value properly.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can i use it on click of check box to get the vale in the same way as you have given?

Comment: Try checkbox change event instead of click